# Storing a named range in a variable and then using that variable to create an array

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a dropdown menu in an excel spreadsheet that consists of the following options:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Which are all named ranges, for example A would refer to a range A5:A20 on a given worksheet. If this dropdown menu is in Cell B5, and then I do something like

```
Dim Storedname as String
Dim namearray as Variant
    Storedname = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value

    Set namearray = Range("Storedname")
```

Why doesn't that work? What do I need to be doing differently?

Comment: Remove the quotes around `Storedname`.

Comment: I've tried that as well but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: What are you expecting that code to do?

Comment: `Set namearray = Range(Storedname)` - namearray isn't an array. If you want it to be an array, `namearray = Range(Storedname).Value`.

Comment: Still not working - I get "Run-time error '1004', Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Comment: That means the `ActiveSheet` doesn't have a range named whatever `Storedname` is.

Comment: Which is weird, because when I put in what is in that variable instead there, it works. So if I put in "A" instead of "Storedname" it will populate the array, but when "A" is in there it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the value of `Storedname` when the error occurs?

Comment: Are all your named ranges on the same sheet?

Comment: They're all workbook level named ranges, would that be the problem? And "A"

Comment: Not necessarily a problem, it means you'll need a different approach then just `Range`.

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out. It was that I wasn't being explicit on the activesheet, thanks for the help! Setting the activesheet to where the named range is didn't work, but doing something like namearray = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Storedname) worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the quotes around `Storedname`.

```
Range(Storedname)
```

Second, in the line

```
Set namearray = Range(Storedname)
```

`namearray` is a  `Variant/Object/Range` because of the `Set`.

Better to be explicit about reading a range into an array - add the `.Value`, and drop the `Set` since that is only for object variables.

```
namearray = Range(Storedname).Value
```

Note - best to qualify the `Worksheet` that the `Range` is on.

Comment: why doesnt this work if you assign your named range as string: i.e. 
```name_range_var = "myrange":

set rng = Range(name_range_var)```

Comment: @mike01010 first suggestion would be to qualify the `Worksheet` that this `Range` belongs to.